# Existing firestore collection data into bigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I have 100 documents in a collection of cloud firestore. I am using firebase extension **Stream Collections to BigQuery** to get the data into google bigQuery. I want to import the existing collection documents into bigQuery using firebase extension **Stream Collections to BigQuery**. Raw changelog table in bigQuery is only getting the Create and Update data of that collection but still can't access the existing documents in the bigQuery.

Kindly help me with some solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the Firebase documentation for the [Stream Collections to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-bigquery-export) extension:

> #### Backfill your BigQuery dataset
>
> This extension only sends the content of documents that have been changed -- it does not export your full dataset of existing documents into BigQuery. So, to backfill your BigQuery dataset with all the documents in your collection, you can run the [import script](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-bigquery-export/guides/IMPORT_EXISTING_DOCUMENTS.md) provided by this extension.
>
> Important: Run the import script over the entire collection after installing this extension, otherwise all writes to your database during the import might be lost.